# Visual basic 6.0, verify a "check" from another project on a project group with an "If" conditional

Tags: if-statement, vb6, project

I am developing a code in Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0, I have a group of projects, inside one of these projects I have a form with a checkbox, which is configured as follows:

```
'Form name: frm_UrlSettings.frm
Private Sub chkUrl_Click()
 executeChange
End Sub
............
```

I want to be able to check in a module of another project that this check is marked, and if so, change the URL to which it redirects. I currently have the code as:

```
'Module name: mod_integration_url
Dim URL_NOTIFICATION As String
URL_NOTIFICATION = "www.myweb.com"
If chkUrl_Click().Value = True Then
........
Else
........
```

And when launching the code it shows me an undefined variable error in "chkUrl_Click", I don't know how it could be done to define that variable in this project. I'm new to this language, so any help is welcome, thanks for all.

Comment: What's the purpose of this? It would help if you explained why this is in a separate project and not in the main app.

Comment: Cause this is a group of projects, and on every project there's a section of the program. The check buttom is on the settings tab, and I the URL that I want to change if the check is activated is on the main tab

Comment: And why are two tabs on the same program located in different executables, which is what different projects represent? Does your entire solution compile into a bunch of exe, which you then launch as needed in order to open and close forms?

Comment: its a single program, that you launch with a main project on this group of projects. To use it you just use "set as default startup" on that main project, and then you launch it.

Comment: Each project must have a type (standard exe, activex exe, activex dll etc). What are the project types of those other projects?

Comment: each project is a "VBP" file

Comment: And what is the project type of the project that is stored in that "VBP" file?

Comment: its an ActiveX DLL

Comment: So you have a main project, presumably exe, and a bunch of other projects each of which compiles to a separate dll. An ActiveX dll is supposed to define classes for other people to instantiate, and presumably the main exe references those classes and instantiates them. So that ActiveX dll class, that wants to examine the form with the checkbox, must provide a way for you to pass that instance to it. So have a property or a method on that class, that you will call at some point from your main executable, passing the instance of that form as the argument.

Comment: Yeah! the main project is an "exe" file. My form is on a DLL project, and I need to verify if its activated on the main project, the "exe" one, how can I do this? I'm really new with this, thanks you

Comment: If you can combine them all into the EXE, do it. That will be much easier to work with. Your multiple DLL structure seems very unnecessary and will cause a lot of extra problems.

Comment: If the checkbox is in a DLL, your difficulty is accessing a specific "instance" of any given form (and hence, checkbox).  What might be easier, without rearranging everything, is to use some signaling mechanism in the middle...  Perhaps write to a file or to the registry?  Then you can read/write the value you need without resolving across different modules, etc.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/savesetting-statement